# Make second request after first is done, csrf Django issue

Tags: django, ajax, redux, csrf

I have a `Redux` app, and there is a component `SalaryComponent` where in its `constructor` I call an `action creator` that makes a request to the server and then `dispatch`es an action, so the state is updated. I need to make the second request to the server after the first one is finished since I need to get some data from the first one to do the second. How would you approach the problem?

> Update

I was able to get the second `ajax` called in the `constructor` like this:

```
props.loadSalary(salary_id).then(() => {
      props.loadData(salary_id)
})
```

I verified that `loadData` gets its argument `salary_id` correctly. But then I am getting the error `Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)`. The first request does not cause `CSRF` error, but the second somehow does. The first request is `GET`, but second is `POST`.

Ultimately I solved it by using `@csrf_exempt` on the `Django` side as a `decorator` to the method I was using to process the second request. Another way is to get `CSRF` token in the browser and use it on the backend.

Comment: All POST requests needs to have your CSRF token.  It sounds like you need to store your CSRF cookie value in your Redux session for chained calls such as this

Comment: Isn't it a security issue? Idk, just asking. Security is extremely important here. If you think it is ok, how could I get CSRF and store it? Backend is Django, and it does not differentiate on a method level between GET and POST, so I would expect no differences actually.

Comment: The CSRF token is available in the browser.  (in Chrome > Applications panel) this will have your local cookies where the CSRF will be.  So no, it's not really a security issue.  That value is used to ensure it matches on the server.  It just ensures that the person making the request is the client the server sent the data too (tokens have to match)

Comment: Ok, got it. Thank you!